# apt-get errors https://pkg.tox.chat/

Tags: apt

I've got toxic client for tox messenger installed. I've started to get some strange warnings and errors after running apt-get:

```
Ign:9 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly InRelease
Ign:10 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly Release
Ign:11 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial amd64 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:12 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial i386 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:13 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial all Packages
Ign:14 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial Translation-en_US
Ign:15 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial Translation-en
Ign:16 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:18 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial amd64 Packages
...(really loads of them)
404  Not Found
Ign:19 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/xenial i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://pkg.tox.chat/debian/dists/nightly/xenial/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So, what's broken and how do i fix it?

Comment: https://pkg.tox.chat/README.txt, they says : `The Debian and Ubuntu package repository was removed per the announcement [1].

[1] https://blog.tox.chat/2018/02/shutdown-of-the-debian-and-ubuntu-package-repository/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pkg.tox.chat` repository was removed, as can be learned from https://pkg.tox.chat/README.txt:

> The Debian and Ubuntu package repository was removed per the announcement [1].
>
> [1] https://blog.tox.chat/2018/02/shutdown-of-the-debian-and-ubuntu-package-repository/
>
> -- nurupo (2018-03-16 02:00 UTC)

Remove the repository from your list of software sources. You can do that either through the Software & Updates system settings GUI, or by removing its respective line from the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` or any of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files, depending on how you added it.